# Android: Activity not registered in the manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, runtimeexception

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.xyz.Main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the Lint-tool tells me that my activity isn't registered in the manifest and if I try to run it, LogCat kindly tells me:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.name/com.xyz.Main.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.Main.MainActivity`

This is driving me nuts, I've re-installed Eclipse as well as updated the SDK and stuff to API-level 17 and now I seem to be unable to execute my very own app. I've got absolutely no idea what the hell's wrong here, apparently the activity is perfectly well registered within the manifest.xml.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure `com.xyz.Main.MainActivity` is the correct package name? and when you say `manifest.xml`, you do mean `AndroidManifest.xml`, correct?

Comment: is your `Activity` class private? if so, change it to public.

Comment: at the top of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you'll see a `package="package_name_here"` attribute. you could try setting your `android:name=".MainActivity"` or something along those lines (where the preceding `.` basically appends the rest of the package name for you). it is identical to writing the entire package name as you've done, but it's gotten to the point where you are re-installing the SDK, it couldn't hurt to try :P

Comment: Didn't work out either. The package-name is 100% correct, simply using a relative path for the class (by the use of a dot) didn't do the job. Neither did re-installing the SDK.

Comment: i guarantee you the error that is causing this is something incredibly stupid too :P. try changing the package name all together. `com.[your last name].[your app name].MainActivity`. and then make sure at the top of your `MainActivity` class, you have `package com.[your last name].[your app name];`

Comment: and by "change the package name" I don't mean simply change the line in your manifest. at this point, if you really have been banging your head against this for the past 2 weeks, it might be a good idea for you to start with a new, 100% fresh project and copy and paste the minimum number of files from your old one to your new one, until you know for certain that it compiles. do this gradually so you know which files cause issues, if any arise.

Comment: packages need to be unique across the android platform... although I've never heard of a package called `com.xyz.Main` (and a subsequent google search confirmed that it probably doesn't exist in the Android SDK... I think), it's bad practice to just type in some random package name when you first create your app. including your name somewhere in there is usually a pretty solid guarantee that you won't run into any conflicts with naming schemes.

Comment: you might also try doing a `Project --> Clean` and then restarting eclipse (this is not performed when you re-install eclipse... your project is completely separate from the IDE)

Comment: I've simply changed the real package name to "com.xyz.Main" for this question; the real package is named after Java-conventions. The app is available on Google Play since January and has been working quite well so far, even though I've not been working on it for weeks. Cleaning didn't help, tried this before. What is entirelly weird is the fact that  if i add the activities via the manifest editor of Eclipse every activity is found and properly added - but the exception remains.

Comment: have you tried creating a new project and starting from there?

Comment: have you tried importing the project in eclipse on a different computer?

Comment: I'm totally screwed here. Even porting the whole app into a fresh Android project (again without capital letters in its package names) didn't change a thing. Lint tells me that none of the activities has been registered in the manifest and so does LogCat when I try to run it. Gotta try this now on a different computer, hopefully that's gonna do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the solution. Today I felt motivated enough get my hands on this project again and tried to port the project to a Linux-distribution (which led me to the conclusion that Linux is a pain in the ass for Android developent) as well as to integrate it "line by line" to a new Android project.

I used to implement String- & Integer-interfaces with certain constants and values (e.g. 0x00 for "visible"). Unfortunately, Android seems to have trouble with interfaces and activity-classes. Removing the interface and making static references onto the constants made the emulator get rid of the problem.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Options // [...]
Btn.setVisibility(VISIBLE); // bad idea

public class MyActivity extends Activity // [...]
Btn.setVisibility(Options.VISIBLE); // good idea
```

Hopefully this is gonna help at least someone searching for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your package name contains a capital letter ("Main"), that might be a problem. Check out this issue on code.google.com:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27529

Comment: This is my guess also.  I ran into this same issue.  You can do a quick fix and disable the check in the project until they get it fixed.  That is what we are doing.

Comment: Didn't work out for me. Changed the package name to lowercase-letters only and noticed no change at all.

Answer (score 2):

If this happens, correct the "package" name (as others have stated) then be sure to re-run "Android Lint".

The warning will stay until Lint has been run again after the correcting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: Lint wouldn't recognize an obviously correct description in AndroidManifest.xml.

I then changed the package name to one with only small alphabethical letters and dots.

The refactor scheme in Eclipse did not rename the package name automatically everywhere, so I had to fix a few situations by hand, like retyping the package name in the manifest file.

When all parts of the application at last referred to the new package name, the Lint was also at last satisfied.

So use capitals and numbers in package names only if you like trouble.

I would like to call this a bug, or at least an annoyance, in Lint, since package names should be allowed to follow Java rules.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message, due to a stupid error on my part. Took me a while to find it, so just in case anyone else makes the same mistake and stumbles on this thread, here's what I'd done wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.DogsDropDown">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
              android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </application>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.DogsDropDown.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</manifest>
```

It's obvious once you see it - I'd placed the <activity> specification outside the <application> specification instead of inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For starting an activity that is not registered in Android Manifest, you can also use this code snippet:

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ValentinAhrend/374c54c04470d4d012d3607b595893c6)