# Unable register Activity in Manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

Before I ask my question I saw [`android intent filter?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701780/android-intent-filter) and [`Android: Activity not registered in the manifest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852864/android-activity-not-registered-in-the-manifest) also I searched [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=activity%20register) ,but I could not find my answer.
In my App,I have to start `Activty1` form `IntentFilterActivity`(both are Activities) with `implicit Intent`.Here is my code:

- Manifest

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.your.namespace"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />

  <application
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <activity
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".IntentFilterActivity" >
          <intent-filter >
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:label="Activity1"
          android:name="com.your.namespace.Activity1" >
          <intent-filter >
              <action android:name="com.your.namespace.MY_MAIN"/>

              <category android:name="com.your.namespace.MY_LAUNCHER"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
  ```
- IntentFilterActivity

  ```
  package com.your.namespace;

  public class IntentFilterActivity extends Activity {
  protected String action = "com.your.namespace.MY_MAIN";
  protected String category = "com.your.namespace.MY_LAUNCHER";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Intent i = new Intent(IntentFilterActivity.this,Activity1.class);
              IntentFilterActivity.this.startActivity(i);
          }
      });

      Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent i = new Intent();
              i.setAction(action);
              i.addCategory(category);
              IntentFilterActivity.this.startActivity(i);
          }
      });
  }
  }
  ```
- Activity1

  ```
  package com.your.namespace;

  public class Activity1 extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main1);
  }
  }
  ```

First I had one button(say `b2`) in `R.layout.main` and in it's onClick event I tried to start Activity1 with implicit Intent.But when I click it I get this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.your.namespace.MY_MAIN cat=[com.your.namespace.MY_LAUNCHER] }
```

So I added another Buuton(say `b1`) to `R.layout.main` and in it's onClick event,I tried to start Activity1 with explicit Intent and Activity1 started fine.So my problem is in about registering Activity1 in manifest.
I tried to change package name,clean/build project,creating a new project and starting from there,importing the project in eclipse on a different computer,restarting eclipse and ... but I get error.My project has only one package(`com.your.namespace`).
What do I do wrong?Please help me to solve this problem.
**Edit**:
When I change Intent filter of Activty1 to this:

```
<intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

and run App, Application's icon appears twice in `Launcher`!This is strange,one intent filter seems to be ignored and another filter,not.

Comment: is your button `b1` could start `activity1`?

Comment: @HelmiB Yes,it starts Activity1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<activity
    android:label="Activity1" android:name="com.your.namespace.Activity1" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.your.namespace.MY_MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

notice the change: **android.intent.category.DEFAULT**

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zelter Ady for his answer,I searched about `startActivity()` and `"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"` and found that ***documentation*** says:

> In principle, therefore, an Intent object with no categories should
>   always pass this test, regardless of what's in the filter. That's
>   mostly true. However, with one exception, Android treats all implicit
>   intents passed to startActivity() as if they contained at least one
>   category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (the CATEGORY_DEFAULT
>   constant). Therefore, activities that are willing to receive implicit
>   intents must include "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in their intent
>   filters. (Filters with "android.intent.action.MAIN" and
>   "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" settings are the exception. They
>   mark activities that begin new tasks and that are represented on the
>   launcher screen. They can include "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in
>   the list of categories, but don't need to.)

I hope this be helped anybody that has same problem.